# Problem with opening deluge

Tags: deluge

whenever I click on deluge bit torrent client. It doesn't open If i try it to open from terminal by typing $ deluge it shows following Error

```
[ERROR   ] 13:56:02 ipcinterface:156 Deluge restart failed: Couldn't listen on any:/home/iamukt/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk: Cannot acquire lock.
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/iamukt/.config/deluge/ipc/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156168) is enlightening for the solution. You should either delete the contents of `~/.config/deluge/ipc/` manually or if the problem persists try to delete them after every reboot. One way to do this is to add this line:

```
rm /home/<<<your.username>>>/.config/deluge/ipc/
```

in `/etc/rc.local`, before the `exit 0` line.

Comment: But this means that the in-progress downloads are lost.